# Display a GUI with two panels including three buttons for each panel

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface, grid-layout

I need help with design and implement a basic GUI with multiple action components. The objective is to create two panels and six buttons. Each panel has three buttons.

So far, I coded in Java Virtual Machine. My codes seem pretty right but the output does not show buttons. Can you help to find why the buttons don't show?

By the way, I have a picture. I want my design like this one.

[image]http://i1199.photobucket.com/albums/aa467/Jordan_Sanjaya/Picture1.png

My code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FlowlayoutExperiment extends JFrame {

    FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout();

    private JButton firstButton = new JButton("Button 1");
    private JButton secondButton = new JButton("Button 2");
    private JButton thirdButton = new JButton("Button 3");
    private JButton fourthButton = new JButton("Button 4");
    private JButton fifthButton = new JButton("Button 5");
    private JButton sixthButton = new JButton("Button 6");

    public FlowlayoutExperiment ()
    {

        JPanel group1 = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        group1.add(firstButton);
        group1.add(secondButton);
        group1.add(thirdButton);        

        JPanel group2 = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        group2.add(fourthButton);
        group2.add(fifthButton);
        group2.add(sixthButton);

         }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

        FlowlayoutExperiment frame = new FlowlayoutExperiment();
        frame.setTitle("Button Panel Example");
        frame.setSize(600, 75);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: You create two panels but you don't add them to the frame.

Comment: Also, neither of the solutions below will work as expected because you can't add two components to the CENTER of a BorderLayout which is the default layout manager for the frame. So you will either need to change the layout of the frame to also be a FlowLayout or you could add one panel to the WEST and the other to the EAST. I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgetten to add the groups to anything

```
public FlowlayoutExperiment ()
{

    JPanel group1 = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    group1.add(firstButton);
    group1.add(secondButton);
    group1.add(thirdButton);        

    JPanel group2 = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    group2.add(fourthButton);
    group2.add(fifthButton);
    group2.add(sixthButton);

    // This is important ;)
    add(group1);
    add(group2);

 }
```

You're also setting the layout of the frame and not the groups

You might want to change...

```
    JPanel group1 = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    //...
    JPanel group2 = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
```

To

```
    JPanel group1 = new JPanel();
    group1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    //...
    JPanel group2 = new JPanel();
    group2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are not displaying. It is because you do not add the 2 JPanels to Frame.

you can add 2 lines codes to constructor FlowlayoutExperiment. And it will make the buttons be shown.
   **this.getContentPane().add(group1);**

**this.getContentPane().add(group2);**

```
public FlowlayoutExperiment() {

    JPanel group1 = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    group1.add(firstButton);
    group1.add(secondButton);
    group1.add(thirdButton);

    JPanel group2 = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    group2.add(fourthButton);
    group2.add(fifthButton);
    group2.add(sixthButton);

    this.getContentPane().add(group1);
    this.getContentPane().add(group2);

}
```

Comment: No need for `getContentPane()`; `JFrame` forwards `add()`